# Document get element BY ID Chrome extension using TYPESCRIPT

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension using Angular / Typescript and I'm trying to get the document element by id from the tab that is active and insert a value. On JS is working fine but on TS I don't know how to do it, because "document.getelementbyId" is not working for "HTML ELEMENT"

So, I used this piece of code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
        if (tab.url == 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/login') {
            

            // THIS IS THE METHOD FOR GET THE ELEMENT BY ID AND IS NOT WORKING
            (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('email')).value = "VALUE";

        }
       
  
    }
  });
```

I hope you understand the question and can help me to do it

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What do you mean by `NOT WORKING`? Did it give you an error? OR the value was not set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`Chrome.tabs` only works on background scripts in v2, or [service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#service-workers) in v3. They both can not access document in current page, you will need to use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) and [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) to achieve this,

I can see you want todo something when a tab has update

You can do this:

- in your service worker

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
        if (tab.url == 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/login') {
            // send message to content script to notify it do something
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: 'updateEmail', data:{emai: VALUE}
        }
    }
  });
```

in your content script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, sender, sendResponse)=>{
 if(req.action === 'updateEmail'){
document.getElementById('email')).value = req.data.email;
}
})
```

And `document.getElementId` can indicate it's return type, so you really don't need to declare type of it.